# Why isn't this int incrementing?

Tags: java, numbers, jlabel, increment

I am stuck on probably an easy problem, but I really can't find why it isn't working. I am trying to increase `mijnScore` with 1 each time the method gets called. But somehow `mijnScore` goes back to 0 after the method is done.

```
int mijnScore = 0;
...
public void updateUI() {
    System.out.println("updateUI");
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {  
            ikWin = true;

            while(ikWin) {
                mijnScore++;
                System.out.println("mijnScore" + mijnScore);
                Scoresp1.setText(mijnScore + "");
                ikWin = false;
                positie = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Solved**

Making the variable static solved my problem.

```
static int mijnScore = 0;
```

Comment: Please include the definition of `mijnScore`. Without it it's rather difficult to figure out the problem.

Comment: Where is `mijnScore` declared? The scope might be important here...

Comment: Have you tried declaring as `static int mijnScore`

Comment: Sorry, `int mijnScore = 0;`  after I declared the class

Comment: Wow making it static actually works. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know wheather you are calling with different objects or same.Just as a guess Make the variable mijnScore static then it may be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the javadoc of the method SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)

It can be that the thread doing the mijnScore increments is invoked only later and this is why in the parent thread you see still the value 0 for it.

Answer (score 1):

why did you set `ikWin = false;` then loop ends in first step

Answer (score 1):

If it works after you made it static, you might actually have a different problem!

Do you call updateUI() on a newly constructed class? If so, only call it on a previously constructed instance as `mijnScore` is local to that instance!

EDIT:

Do your classes look like this? (Maybe you should have posted more code in the question)

```java
// Score.java
public class Score {

    int mijnScore = 0;

    JLabel scoreSp1 = new JLabel();

    public Score(JDialog dialog) {
            dialog.add(scoreSp1);
    }

    ...

    public void updateUI() {
        // Code from question
    }
}

// Window.java
public class Game {

    ...

    public void scoredPoint() {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog("You scored!");
        new Score(dialog).updateUI();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In this silly example, the problem is actually in the second class - you shouldn't create a new `Score` instance every time. For the example, the code should be written like this:

```java
// Window.java
public class Game {

    JDialog dialog = new JDialog("You scored!");

    Score score = new Score(dialog);

    ...

    public void scoredPoint() {
        score.updateUI();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I do , could this also be the problem why my label won't change its text?

Comment: @Jef See, you only moved the problem. Edit your question to reveal more of the class structure and how your calls work.

Maybe post the two classes you are working with to show us what you are actually doing with updateUI().

Comment: Can I ask it here? Since its actually another subject

Comment: I believe it's actually part of the same problem and hence can be asked here.

Comment: @Jef You didn't post any new code, so I just made up an example.