# JLabel won't change after setText in Java

Tags: java, jlabel

I got a JLabel `Scoresp1` which I want to change using `Scoresp1.setText(mijnScore + "");`. But the text on the JLabel stays the same.

I got a class `Dobbelsteen` which looks like this:

```
public class Dobbelsteen extends Spel {

    ...

    public void aantalOgen(int aantalogen) {

        oudepositie = huidigepositie;
        nieuwepositie = (huidigepositie + aantalOgen);
        if (nieuwepositie == eindronde) {
            System.out.println("Speler Piet heeft de ronde gewonnen!");
            updateUI();
        }
    }
}
```

Which calls updateUI which is in the class `Spel`

```
public class Spel {
    ...
   public void updateUI() {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {  
               ikWin = true;
               while(ikWin){
                   mijnScore = mijnScore+1;
                   Scoresp1.setText(mijnScore + "");
                   System.out.println("mijnScore" + mijnScore);
                   ikWin = false;
                   positie = 0;
                   }
              }

          });
       }
    ...
}
```

`Scoresp1` is declared as `public JLabel Scoresp1;`. If I use `String l = Scoresp1.getText();` I get the right value, but the JLabel doesn't get updated visually.

Comment: Since this problem eventually boils down to "spot the mistake in this code", it would help if you could just zip your whole project and upload it somewhere. There just isn't enough code to work on, just like  [your other question on this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753369/why-isnt-this-int-incrementing)

Comment: how about the output from `System.out.println("mijnScore" + mijnScore);` print something???,

Comment: @Bert, thanks for your offer. I've uploaded my project here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3138678/Paardenspel.rar The project has a lot of flaws at the moment, but step by step I'm hoping to complete it soon.

Comment: @mKorbel the output is the same value as the label should be.

Comment: @Jef then how value is in the last  System.out.println("mijnScore" + mijnScore);, then same value you can see in the JLabel,

Comment: @mKorbel The label doesn't change it stays 0, but the value  of `System.out.println("mijnScore" + mijnScore);` is the value which the label should have. The `getText` gives the same value as the println.

Comment: You should not be calling updateUI in a Swing application unless you are using it to change the L&F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at some of you code, and my first concern (other than an over-use of static variables) is that you're using inheritance inappropriately and because of this are calling methods on the wrong reference.

Many classes inherit from Spel but don't appear that they should be doing this.  For instance, your Dobbelsteen class inherits from Spel, and yet it also has a separate Spel instance -- why? What Spel object is currently visible at the time this code is run?  I doubt it is the one that Dobbelsteen extends. Because of this, I think that you're trying to changing the JLabel that is held by the the Dobbelsteen class, but it is not the "Spel" object that is currently visualized. To properly change the visualized JLabel, you'll need a valid reference to the currently visualized Spel object that holds it, and call the appropriate public method on that class.

In all, you might want to re-write this project from the ground up, with a goal of separating out your model (the data) from the view (the GUI), and with an eye towards good OOP principles.

**Edit 1:**

This may only be a bandaid, but what if you got your Spel reference passed to you in Dobbelsteen's constructor, something like this (changes noted with !! comments: //!!):

```
//!! public class Dobbelsteen extends Spel {
public class Dobbelsteen { //!!

   int dobbelsteen;
   int nieuwepositie;
   int nieuwepositie2;
   public static String newPos;
   public static String newPos2;
   int oudepositie;
   int oudepositie2;
   int huidigepositie = Spel.positie;
   // int huidigepositie2 = Spel.positie2;
   int aantalOgen = Spel.aantalogen;
   int aantalOgen2 = Spel.aantalogen2;
   static boolean heeftgewonnen = false;

   // !! Spel spiel = new Spel();
   Spel spiel; // !!

   // !!
   public Dobbelsteen(Spel spiel) {
      this.spiel = spiel;
   }

   public void aantalOgen(int aantalogen) {
      oudepositie = huidigepositie;
      nieuwepositie = (huidigepositie + aantalOgen);
      if (nieuwepositie == Spel.eindronde) { //!!
         System.out.println("Speler Piet heeft de ronde gewonnen!");
         spiel.updateUI(); //!! ****** here in particular ******
      } else if (nieuwepositie > Spel.eindronde) {
         Spel.positie = huidigepositie; //!!
         spiel.output.setText("Je hebt teveel gegooid"); //!!
         spiel.output.setForeground(Color.red); //!!
      } else {
         Spel.oudpositie = oudepositie; //!!
         Spel.positie = nieuwepositie; //!!
         newPos = String.valueOf(nieuwepositie);
         if (SpelHost.host) {
            SpelHost.verstuurPositie("Positie" + newPos);
         } else if (SpelClient.client) {
            SpelClient.verstuurPositie("Positie" + newPos);
         }
      }

   }
}
```

And call it like so:

```
class GooiDobbelsteen extends MouseAdapter {

   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      aanBeurt = false;
      dobbelsteen = new Random();
      aantalogen = dobbelsteen.nextInt(6) + 1;
      aantalOog = String.valueOf(aantalogen);
      Dobbelsteen dobbel = new Dobbelsteen(Spel.this); // !!
      dobbel.aantalOgen(aantalogen);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My code has a lot of unused code. I put the Spel instance in Dobbelsteen to try somethings but I forgot to delete it. My programming skills aren't good, i'm a student and still learning.

Comment: @Jef: This still begs the question -- which "Spel" object is the one that is being displayed? Which class has the main class that starts everything? Which class has the code that calls setVisible(true) on a GUI type object?

Comment: The Spel object which is being displayed is called in Lobby `spelscherm = new Spel();`. Both SpelClient and SpelHost are the main classes, one for the host and one for the client. Each component added to the frame gets added in StartScherm, Lobby and Spel ,there isn't one class for the GUI.

I do use variables from Dobbelsteen to change the background colors from the JButtons in Spel, which works fine.

Comment: @Jef: Please see **Edit 1** above.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for your time. Works as a charm after implementing the message method.

Comment: @Jef: You're welcome. The key is not to use inheritance when what you need is in fact a proper reference.

Answer (score 0):

use
     public void updateUI() {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               ikWin = true;
               while(ikWin){
                   mijnScore = mijnScore+1;
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {

```
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Scoresp1.setText(mijnScore + "");

                }
            });

               System.out.println("mijnScore" + mijnScore);
               ikWin = false;
               positie = 0;
               }
          }

      });
   }
```

to have a test

Answer (score -1):

Add a `Scoresp1.repaint()` to the end of your while loop.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but adding `repaint` to the end of the while loop doesn't work.

Comment: repaint is not necessary nor helpful in this situation. -1.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: your comment isn't valid either. You never have to call repaint, validate, revalidate, or similar methods to coax a JLabel to change its text when setText(...) has been called appropriately. The label will do this on its own. The error lies elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, woops.  Thanks for the heads up about `setText`.